# Have you met Vera?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Maybe St. Paul's Hospital admitted Polanski's wife, approximately half-hour missing (5,7)
>   7. Moving canoe to the sea (5)
>   8. Natural bottled water brand is all about having tea (6)
>   10. Vera's picture includes food that looks like jelly (5)
>   12. Adam's wife seen with new man (4)
>   13. Singing groups are rich – so ludicrous (6)
>   15. Vera recognized prisoners, which is extraordinary (4)
>   16. Can Tool be a warm-up band? (6)
>   18. Ruby's victim was old, in a way (6)
>   20. Actor played slowly, with no heart (4)
>   21. Setting for a boxing thriller: man facing heavyweight champion making comeback (6)
>   23. Venereal disease near Russia's capital leads to uproar (4)
>   24. Music's mystery woman novelised in part (5)
>   26. Secretly charm an Italian fashion designer (6)
>   28. Vera making third small, quiet motor vehicle (5)
>   29. Strange things – having, perhaps, stout doormen working graveyard shift (5,7)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Repository for Oscars collected by Halle Berry's role about Sun god (9)
>   2. Vera about to grow old and mean (7)
>   3. Woman with a bit of elephant DNA (4)
>   4. Poor comparison to fortified chambers (5,5)
>   5. Bird central to article in *Times* (3)
>   6. Twist off the head to get internal organ (5)
>   9. Vera's foot and, mostly, chest pains (5)
>   11. South of France vacation involving Dalí (needing no introduction) and maybe Magritte (10)
>   14. "They're off the beaten path", groaned Cecil to anyone listening (4,5)
>   17. Page from *Inception* screenplay, essentially about central trio of killers (5)
>   19. Performer's flashy attires (7)
>   22. Vera pronounces covering "covering" (5)
>   25. Always last in line, Vera lost final (4)
>   27. Vera the fashion designer heading away to be a film director (3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grid:

> [image: grid]

**Across**

1. Maybe St. Paul's Hospital admitted Polanski's wife, approximately half-hour missing (5,7)

> STATE CAPITAL (maybe st. paul's, HOS(TATE + CA)PITAL - HO_)

7. Moving canoe to the sea (5)

> OCEAN (sea, CANOE*)

8. Natural bottled water brand is all about having tea (6)

> NATIVE (natural, EVI(T)AN<)

10. Vera's picture includes food that looks like jelly (5)

> ASPIC (food that looks like jelly, _AS PIC_)

12. Adam's wife seen with new man (4)

> EVAN (man, EVA + N)

13. Singing groups are rich – so ludicrous (6)

> CHOIRS (singing groups, RICH SO*)

15. Vera recognized prisoners, which is extraordinary (4)

> RARE (extraordinary, _RA RE_)

16. Can Tool be a warm-up band? (6)

> OPENER (ddef)

18. Ruby's victim was old, in a way (6)

> OSWALD (ruby's victim, WAS OLD*)

20. Actor played slowly, with no heart (4)

> LETO (actor, LENTO - N)

21. Setting for a boxing thriller: man facing heavyweight champion making comeback (6)

> MANILA (setting for a boxing thriller, MAN + ALI<)

23. Venereal disease near Russia's capital leads to uproar (4)

> STIR (uproar, STI + R_)

24. Music's mystery woman novelised in part (5)

> ELISE (music's mystery woman, _ELISE_)

26. Secretly charm an Italian fashion designer (6)

> ARMANI (fashion designer, _ARM AN I_)

28. Vera making third small, quiet motor vehicle (5)

> VESPA (motor vehicle, VE(R->SP)A)

29. Strange things – having, perhaps, stout doormen working graveyard shift (5,7)

> NIGHT PORTERS (doormen working graveyard shift, THING(PORTER)S*)

**Down**

1. Repository for Oscars collected by Halle Berry's role about Sun god (9)

> STOREROOM (repository, STO(RE)(OO)RM)

2. Vera about to grow old and mean (7)

> AVERAGE (mean, VERA* + AGE)

3. Woman with a bit of elephant DNA (4)

> EDNA (woman, E_ + DNA)

4. Poor comparison to fortified chambers (5,5)

> PANIC ROOMS (fortified chambers, COMPARISON*)

5. Bird central to article in Times (3)

> TIT (bird, T(_I_)T)

6. Twist off the head to get internal organ (5)

> LIVER (internal organ, OLIVER - O)

9. Vera's foot and, mostly, chest pains (5)

> ACHES (pains, _A + CHES_)

11. South of France vacation involving Dalí (needing no introduction) and maybe Magritte (10)

> SURREALIST (maybe magritte, SUR + RE(ALI)ST)

14. "They're off the beaten path", groaned Cecil to anyone listening (4,5)

> SIDE ROADS (they're off the beaten path, SIGHED RHODES homophone(thanks @postmortes))

17. Page from Inception screenplay, essentially about central trio of killers (5)

> ELLEN (page from inception, _E(_LLE_)N_)

19. Performer's flashy attires (7)

> ARTISTE (performer, ATTIRES*)

22. Vera pronounces covering "covering" (5)

> APRON (covering, _A PRON_)

25. Always last in line, Vera lost final (4)

> EVER (always, _E + VER_)

27. Vera the fashion designer heading away to be a film director (3)

> ANG (film director, WANG - W)

Comment: @postmortes (and anyone else interested): [Cecil Rhodes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecil_Rhodes)